# Responsive Div between two fixed Divs

Tags: css, responsive-design

Good afternoon.

This is my first responsive layout, and from what I've read, I am trying to build one.

I made a fiddle that represents my work so far, and I'm stuck.

I have the parent relative width, that it is set to take 90% of the screen, and be centered (vertically and horizontally).

Within that div, there is another 3 sections, the first one is absolute-sized at 160px height, the second one is relative (from my calculations, it is something near 77.56%), and the third one is another absolute-sized at 30px height.

**So my two questions are:**

-The wrap div is properly aligned at fullscreen (1920x1080), but as it reaches low resolutions, the sides of that div begin to overflow (vertical and horizontal), how do I fix this?

-The calculations on the three divs doesn't seem to be correct at different heights (as it begins to overflow from the wrap div aswell).

***OBS: In the fiddle, the mid-div height doesn't seem to work, i don't know why.***

(

```
#wrap div#content{
    position:relative;
    background-color: teal;
    height: 77.5678866593353%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

)

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKQfg/1/

Sorry, but I think that these questions are a mess, I can't explain it well.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the % heights? If a div expands to a % height, then the parent expands too. Then it has to be recalculated infinitely. That's why % heights are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the border and padding. To center an element, give it auto margin-left and right. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKQfg/2/).

```
div#wrap { margin: 0 auto 2.5% }
```